# Insert and read data from Sqlite over SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have question about passing data between activities. Is possible from main activity open few next activities, and return result from last opened to root activity and how? I've added screenshot for better vision what I mean. Thanks for answers.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0u1j0.png)

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: can you tell me how ?

Comment: Start the first `Activity` from the third one and pass the data in the `Intent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with this question @Sahil Lombar

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
i.putExtra("data", "data");
startActivity(i);
```

in other activity we can

```
//firt validate if value extra "data" it was sent
   if(getIntent().hashExtra("data") {
   String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
   Log.d("SecondActivity", value);
   }
```

working with String, int, boolean, double, Byte and array of these

more.. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Start the First Activity with Intent holding the result;

In Activity 3

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
i.putExtra("data", "data");
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

In Activity 1 receive the result in public void onNewIntent or if you are starting a new activity in the onCreate method

```
public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
Intent i = getIntent();
String result = i.getStringExtra("data");
}
```

Comment: but I want start again main activity ... I want after clicking on some item in 3. activity finish it and get back my main activity with result from 3.